# How to use DPLYR to get by group summary and record count

Tags: r, dplyr

I am trying to use DPLYR to create a dataframe that has three variables: REGION, total SALES in the region, total sales RECORDS in the region. I can use 2 passes through DPLYR and a merge to get exactly what I want. But there should be a way to use one pass through DPLYR to get what I am after.

Randomly Generate a df that has sales by each of 10 regions

```
library(dplyr)
set.seed(2222)
sales   <- sample.int(100, 1000, replace = TRUE)
regions <- sample.int(10,  1000, replace = TRUE)
analysis_df <- data.frame(sales, regions)
```

Target: Want to build a df with one DPLYR script that has the following structure

```
    Region   rows/records   sum(sales)
     1          96               4997
     2          97               4932
     3         105               5084
    ...
    10        106               5080
```

I can get what I want with two sets of DPLYR script and a merge

```
region_n <- analysis_df  %>%
  group_by(regions) %>%
  summarise(n = n() )
region_n 

sales_sum <- analysis_df %>%
  group_by(regions) %>%
  summarise(sum.sales = sum(sales))
sales_sum

sales_fin <- merge(region_n, sales_sum, by=c("regions")) 
sales_fin
```

But this seems like it should be unnecessary. There should be a way to make one pass with DPLYR to get what I want. More or less like....

```
sales_fin2 <- analysis_df  %>%
  group_by(regions) %>%
  summarise(n = n() ) %>%
  summarise(sum.sales = sum(sales))
sales_fin2
```

But this simply returns one record with a sum of sales across all regions and seems to ignore the by group processing.
Thoughts?

Comment: The `summarise` function takes multiple arguments. Just replace the second `) %>%
  summarise(` with `, `

Comment: THANKS I appreciated the straight-forward answer to what I know is a simple question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @IceCreamToucan mentioned

```
analysis_df  %>%
  group_by(regions) %>%
  summarise(
    n = n(),
    sum.sales = sum(sales)
  )
```

Comment: Thanks! Helps my understanding of DPLYR.